# Remove lag in AS3 tiling program

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, lag, tile

QUERY

I am creating a program that has a lot of tiles in the environment that are all movie clips. The player can move around in this environment. How can I hide the tiles that are off the screen to decrease lag?

The tiles are all in a 2D array that is 20 horizontal units by 10 vertical units.
Let me know if you have any suggestions!

MORE INFO

I have a Tile class for the tile, so I can add functions for removal within this. I'm just unsure how to go about it.

-Olin

Comment: You may want to investigate using some existing tile based game platform for AS3 like Flixel or check out this page http://www.ironcoding.com/2011/02/flash-as3-tile-based-game-tutorial-pt-1-intro/ or check out this page if you're into the idea of using Stage3D to get GPU based performance benefits http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/games/build-a-stage3d-shoot-em-up-sprite-test/

Comment: Alternatively to do this by yourself I'd suggest coming up with a system for keeping track of the "current position" in Cartesian coordinates and the width and height of the "view port" with these three pieces of information you can calculate what the top left and bottom right tiles will be and include all of the tiles in between.

Comment: Simplest things that come to mind are: 1. If youre tiles are inside a Sprite, try to use the `scrollRect` property which kind of works like a mask. 2. If that doesn't work, try to do basic blitting (draw all the tiles into a single larger BitmapData, then, depending on what area needs to be diplayed use the BitmapData's `copyPixels` method to copy the right area from tiles to display in the visible area). This is just for a basic test. @shaunhusain's advice is very useful

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for how to do some more fine grained memory management by recollecting memory from tiles no longer on screen, in Flash or any other language that results in bytecode that is then run in a virtual machine that handles the low level memory management and garbage collection, your control is limited with regard to reclaiming memory.  Your best bet in these instances is to use object pools to dynamically allocate the number of objects you need then retain them and simply mark them as unused when they're ready to be recycled.

Read up on object pooling in AS3 here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS948100b6829bd5a6-19cd3c2412513c24bce-8000.html

or on working with the garbage collector here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS4bebcd66a74275c3-576ba64d124318d7189-7ffc.html

All part of the top level (conserving memory):
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS4bebcd66a74275c333637c44124318c9bf9-8000.html

even though this is all in the mobile dirctory I'm willing to bet the information is just as pertinent on the desktop.